# Stateless Apache Airflow Service

Tags: airflow, cloud-foundry

I have been searching through many articles and the official documentation for [Apache Airflow](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/) and have successfully configured things to utilize a local postgres instance for the service's metadata.  One thing I cannot figure out thus far is if Apache Airflow DAGs can be defined within my database as well, rather than in a folder relative to the airflow folder location.

My goal is to have a stateless Airflow service deployed with Cloud Foundry, and thus I cannot rely on any DAG configuration files stored on the machine.  Is there a way to deploy Airflow to Cloud Foundry in such a way that the DAG configuration files are dynamically retrieved from a remote database?

Comment: does the code used by the dags need to be stateless? for example if i have class that instantiates with some member variables that store meta data about where to get various data sources...and has methods that use those member variables to fetch various data.  can i call say 2 different methods in parallel from the same instance of the class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [DAG serialization](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/dag-serialization.html) feature. It has limitations though:

> **Limitations**
>
> The Webserver will still need access to DAG files in the following cases, which is why we said “almost” stateless.
>
> - Rendered Template tab will still have to parse Python file as it needs all the details like the execution date and even the data passed by the upstream task using Xcom.
> - Code View will read the DAG File & show it using Pygments. However, it does not need to Parse the Python file so it is still a small operation.